# activerecord records not in the :through condition

Tags: activerecord

I need to get the records not in the :through condition.

I have 3 tables:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B_A
  has_many :B, through: :B_A
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B_A
  has_many :A, through: :B_A
end
class BA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :A
  belongs_to :B
end
```

I get all A linked to a specific B by `listOfA = B.A` but I need also to get all A not in any B. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had two conditions to put in my join query.
My MySql was :

```
select a.`id`, a.`label`
from `A` a
left join `BA` ba
on a.`id` = ba.`a`
where a.`uid`='userId'
and ba.`a` is null
```

My activeRecord now is :

```
A.select(['A.id', :label])
  .joins('left outer join B_A on B_A.a_id = A.id')
  .where({ user_id: current_user.id, "B_A.a_id" => nil })
```

And I have all my A not in BA